# Rails 5: Why won't my image asset load in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an image in the images folder in assets: `app/assets/images/memphis-mini.png`.

I am using this image as a background.

```
.hero {
  background-image: url('memphis-mini.png');
}
```

In development, it works as expected. Rails finds the image and the background displays accordingly.

However, in production, the image cannot be found. Looking in the console, I can see that the app appears to be looking for the image in the wrong place:

```
https://billbillapp.herokuapp.com/assets/memphis-mini.png
```

Why isn't it looking in the images folder? Should it be looking in the images folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [Rails asset helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

```
.hero {
   background-image: url(image_path('memphis-mini.png'));
}
```

Also you must use `.scss` as the filename ending for your stylesheet. This way Rails generates the correct url for you.